# Query optimization, slow index scan

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to optimize a query on Posygres. The table dgt_ip_minute_stats is often updated by batch jobs. The table structure:

```
\d dgt_ip_minute_stats;
          Materialized view "public.dgt_ip_minute_stats"
         Column     |            Type             | Modifiers 
    ----------------+-----------------------------+-----------
     techid         | integer                     | 
     timestamp      | timestamp without time zone | 
     t_interval     | integer                     | 
     network_id     | integer                     | 
     unique_id      | bigint                      | 
     modem_sn       | integer                     | 
     rx_tcp_kbyte   | double precision            | 
     tx_tcp_kbyte   | double precision            | 
     rx_udp_kbyte   | double precision            | 
     tx_udp_kbyte   | double precision            | 
     rx_icmp_kbyte  | double precision            | 
     tx_icmp_kbyte  | double precision            | 
     rx_igmp_kbyte  | double precision            | 
     tx_igmp_kbyte  | double precision            | 
     rx_http_kbyte  | double precision            | 
     tx_http_kbyte  | double precision            | 
     rx_other_kbyte | double precision            | 
     tx_other_kbyte | double precision            | 
    Indexes:
        "idx_dgt_min_stat_time_ntw_uq" UNIQUE, btree ("timestamp", network_id, unique_id)
        "dgt_ip_minute_stats_network_id_idx" btree (network_id)
        "dgt_ip_minute_stats_timestamp_idx" btree ("timestamp")
        "dgt_ip_minute_stats_unique_id_idx" btree (unique_id)
        "dgt_ip_minute_stats_unique_id_network_id_idx" btree (unique_id, network_id)
```

the table is large and it has 4975883 records. 
this is the query, i am trying to optmize:

```
EXPLAIN(ANALYZE) 
SELECT (EXTRACT(epoch from date_trunc('day',dgt_ip_minute_stats.timestamp)
               ) * 1000)::BIGINT as dgt_ip_minute_stats_timestamp,
    SUM((tx_udp_kbyte)/(8 * 1024))::FLOAT AS up_udp_kbyte,
    SUM((rx_udp_kbyte)/(8 * 1024))::FLOAT AS down_udp_kbyte,
    SUM((tx_http_kbyte)/(8 * 1024))::FLOAT AS up_http_kbyte,
    SUM((rx_http_kbyte)/(8 * 1024))::FLOAT AS down_http_kbyte,  
    SUM((tx_tcp_kbyte)/(8 * 1024))::FLOAT AS up_tcp_kbyte,
    SUM((rx_tcp_kbyte)/(8 * 1024))::FLOAT AS down_tcp_kbyte  
FROM dgt_remote_terminal
INNER JOIN dgt_ip_minute_stats 
   ON  dgt_ip_minute_stats.unique_id = dgt_remote_terminal.netmodemid 
  AND  dgt_ip_minute_stats.network_id = dgt_remote_terminal.networkid
WHERE (terminalid = 117529178) 
GROUP BY dgt_ip_minute_stats_timestamp
ORDER BY dgt_ip_minute_stats_timestamp ASC;
```

and the explain result:

```
 Sort  (cost=51353.37..51417.41 rows=25615 width=56) (actual time=28875.682..28875.685 rows=31 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (((date_part('epoch'::text, date_trunc('day'::text, dgt_ip_minute_stats."timestamp")) * 1000::double precision))::bigint)
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 29kB
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=48965.45..49477.75 rows=25615 width=56) (actual time=28875.572..28875.648 rows=31 loops=1)
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=198.90..47026.44 rows=59662 width=56) (actual time=160.024..28586.375 rows=86383 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on dgt_remote_terminal  (cost=0.00..6.74 rows=2 width=6) (actual time=8.306..101.832 rows=2 loops=1)
                     Filter: (terminalid = 117529178)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 137
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on dgt_ip_minute_stats  (cost=198.90..23134.99 rows=7655 width=68) (actual time=131.149..14014.867 rows=43192 loops=2)
                     Recheck Cond: ((unique_id = dgt_remote_terminal.netmodemid) AND (network_id = dgt_remote_terminal.networkid))
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on dgt_ip_minute_stats_unique_id_network_id_idx  (cost=0.00..196.98 rows=7655 width=0) (actual time=56.721..56.721 rows=43192 loops=2)
                           Index Cond: ((unique_id = dgt_remote_terminal.netmodemid) AND (network_id = dgt_remote_terminal.networkid))
 Total runtime: 28878.998 ms
(13 rows)
```

What puzzles me is that the index scan is slow! At least at the first run,
then the query is performing better, probably because the index is cached. 
But after few runs, it becomes slow again.
I cannot find other ways to optimize it. What are the possible cause of a slow index scan at first run? and why the performance degrades after few runs? the updates on the table can invalidate the index cache?
autovaccum is ON on my database, so i suppose i should not have too many t-nuples

Comment: `dgt_remote_terminal` also have index  `btree (unique_id, network_id)` ? and you need one index for `terminalid` I bet that would improve your speed a lot.